# Pass argument and handle multiply tab at a same time Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to open 4 tab with google maps and pass "japan" keyword into the search box at the same time but it doesnt  seem to work properly,it send "japan" 4 time into search box of the second tab.How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import threading
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By




options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\data')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
def axe(x):

 driver.execute_script('window.open("https://www.google.com/maps");')
 driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x])
 time.sleep(10)
 driver.find_element(By.ID,"searchboxinput").send_keys("japan ")
 driver.find_element(By.ID,"searchbox-searchbutton").click()
threads =[]
for i in range (4):
    t =threading.Thread (target=axe, args=[i])
    t.start()
    threads.append (t)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: It has something to do with how you defined your handles. Refer this => https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opening-multiple-tabs-using-selenium/

Comment: i found that is a system error webdriver not a good choice for multithread